# Change page dynamically using th:if and th:replcae in thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Here are my controllers:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/user/edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String editForm(@PathVariable Integer id,Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("UserInfo", userService.getUserById(id));
    return "EditUser";
}


   @RequestMapping(value="/moduleList", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String moduleList(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("moduleCommand", new Module());
        model.addAttribute("moduleList", applicationService.getAllModules());
        return "modulelist";
    }
```

rightSection.html

```
    <div th:fragment="rightSectionBar">
    <div class="container body">
        <div class="title_section" style="margin-top: 50px;">
            <div class="col-md-2 heading">
                <h4>Home</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9 right_col">
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
            <!-- page content -->
            <span th:replace="fragments/contents::dashboard"></span> 

//I want to see below content on calling "/user/edit/{id}" url
            <span th:replace="fragments/EditUser::editUsersBar"></span>

//I want to see below content on calling "/moduleList" url
            <span th:replace="fragments/modulelist::modulesListBar"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to keep sidemenu and top navigation same on every page and just want to change right section content only.

Comment: You can write something like `<th:block th:if="${UserInfo}"> <span th:replace="fragments/EditUser::editUsersBar"></span></th:block>`. Similarly another block for the other span.

Comment: Thanks, @Sujit, this worked for me :)

Comment: Glad I could help, I have added this as an answer, would be great if you can approve it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `th:block` and `th:if` for this purpose. Thymeleaf will execute the attributes within `th:block` will make the it disappear as `th:block` is a mere attribute container.

```
<div class="col-md-9 right_col">
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<span th:replace="fragments/contents::dashboard"></span> 

<th:block th:if="${UserInfo}">
    <span th:replace="fragments/EditUser::editUsersBar"></span>
</th:block>
<th:block th:if="${moduleCommand}">
    <span th:replace="fragments/modulelist::modulesListBar"></span>
</th:block>
</div>
```